# Azure Pipeline Data Sync

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database, devops

We have some databases(10 databses) in dev and test environments on Azure SQL. We would like to be able to sync the data between environments using the **azure pipeline**.

The Schema changes happen automagically with entity framework migrations which is fine.

For syncing data, We've created a data compare in visual studio that we use to sync the data on demand. Now we would like to automate this process(syncing data).

Is there an existing task that we can add to the pipeline to run this data compare and subsequent sync?

Comment: So you want to sync data between environments, but I don't understand the part with Entity Framework. Is there any issue with this?

Comment: Entity Framework works fine, the schema is updated by migration file(it is a task in our release pipeline). I would like to create a pipeline for syncing the data between the two environments.

Comment: What about SQL Data Sync for Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [SQL Data Sync for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database).

And what it does:

> SQL Data Sync is a service built on Azure SQL Database that lets you synchronize the data you select bi-directionally across multiple databases, both on-premises and in the cloud.

Fir you need to:

- create sync group - on your prod database
- use sync members - here you will use your test database
- than configure group sync

What is cool about that you can select what particularly should be synced:

[image]

You can then trigger that from azure pipelines calling

```
Start-AzSqlSyncGroupSync -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName $databaseName -SyncGroupName $syncGroupName
```

from [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops). If you define [cron schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) you will get you data up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I found that the sync process was putting a significant load on the databases. I guess it is constantly scraping the source DB or doing some other things. Overall controls are very limited

Comment: It is depends, how many data you have. Even creating simple backup and restoring database could be heavy. If you can scale up database before sync and then scale it down it may help you (this is for instance recommended approach on migration). And if you don't need daily sync you can schedule it for once a week, on a time when you don't expect a traffic on you page.